# Search error while using Datatable with huge data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datatable, datatables

I have around 5,00,000 records in my database. I'm using DataTables to build an admin panel to manage the records.
I have Node.js as backed with MongoDB.

I have used this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables-query

So far on page load I have successfully loaded results a shown in the below Image.

[image]

Whenever I type something in the search box, I get 500 error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Is DataTable a good option for showing grid with huge amount of data or is there any better option considering Node.js, Express and MongoDB combo?

Here is my server side code.

```
app.post('/getUsersData',function(req, res) {
  var Model = require('./models/user'),
    datatablesQuery = require('datatables-query'),
    params = req.body,
    query = datatablesQuery(Model);

  query.run(params).then(function (users) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(users);
    // var data = JSON.stringify(users);

    res.end(data);
  }, function (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  });
});
```

I have a table in MongoDB named User with 3 columns

1) Name

2) Email

3) Password

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    // dom: 'Bfrtip',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 0 ], visible: false } ], // first column in visible columns array gets class "hide_me"
    ajax: {
        url: "/getUsersData",
        type: 'POST',
        dataSrc: "data"
    },
    columns: [
        { data : "_id"},
        { data : "name" },
        { data : "email" },
        { data : "password" },
   ],
   responsive: true
  });
});
```

Comment: if you have specific columns (and possibly relational data) why the choice of MongoDb ? (not critique, just curious )

Comment: While learning NodeJS in most of the tutorials, the tutors were using MongoDB, so I went ahead with it. Would you suggest any other database?

Comment: That's a question with very opinionated asweres, where you can easily spark a no-sql vs sql war, but that said, I use both, postresql for relational data (there is plenty node pgsql drivers) and mongo for loose or prepared data. If you already know SQL, I don't see the point in having to change that just because you learn a new language.

Comment: Add `console.log(err)` before `res.status(500).json(err);`, and take a look what it prints in terminal.

Comment: I can't think of a use case where you'd want to store and display passwords. You should salt and hash passwords veggie storing.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably create an index on the data and search that index rather than searching the data itself. If you do however create a full text index you need to have a combination off all your cols in your collection and mongo [allows only 1 full text index per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

As for alternatives, you could look into AWS's Elastic Search (which works just fine with MongoDB) or Sphinx Index (based on PostreSQL)

Edit: 
I know this answer doesn't actually answer the question in the slightest but 
I fear that the 500 error is not a memory issue in the application but rather on the DB (mongo is not like SQL, so don't design your applications like you would in SQL).

Some reading material, if you plan on changing db structure

http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/ 
https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/

Comment: The 500 status code is being explicitly returned in OP's code, and doesn't necessarily indicate what the underlying problem is.

Comment: I did say that, but one can only guess with limited information

Answer (score 1):

The key here is figuring out what exactly went wrong on the DB or server side layer. The error message that you are alerting out is a generic message from the datatables library which points you to the following documentation: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

The documentation linked to above says that this error will occur anytime a non-200 response is returned from the server. In this case you are explicitly throwing a 500 error in the error handler/callback of the datatables query call, but that doesn't give you/us the information we need!

The next step is to look at the response body in the network tab of your browser's console, since you are serializing the error as json and sending it along with your 500 response, or to `console.log` out the `err` in the error handler/callback in your node code. This will get you an understanding of what is actually going wrong, and with that information we can more accurately prescribe a solution. Post an update with whatever you log out please!

Answer (score 0):

here is solution i tried to fix this issue:
goto ur jquery.datatable.min.js and then comment out the error message and you are good to go.

```
function K(a, b, c, d) {
        // c = "DataTables warning: " + (a ? "table id=" + a.sTableId + " - " : "") + c;
        // d && (c += ". For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/" + d);
        // if (b) E.console && console.log && console.log(c); else if (b = n.ext, b = b.sErrMode || b.errMode, a && r(a, null, "error", [a, d, c]), "alert" == b) alert(c); else {
        //     if ("throw" == b) throw Error(c);
        //     "function" ==
        //     typeof b && b(a, d, c)
        // }
    }
```